# efficient way to find last week customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns(customerid, date_purchased, item) table with 2 weeks of data. I want to retrieve the customers that only bought from the first week. My logic is to find the max date subtract it all the rest of the dates and retrieve customers where that difference equal or less than 7. Here is what I did, but I have a problem with my query.

```
   select distinct(customerid) from customer where datediff(max(date_purchased),Orderdate)<=7;
```

Comment: Is the problem an error from mysql or are the results not what you expect?

Comment: Your query says that the difference has to be exactly 7, not equal or less than 7

Comment: You said last week, but then you want customers bought from the first week. In your sql you are trying to find customers purchased exactly in one week from ordering. What is is that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct customerid
from customer
where date_purchased > (
    select max(date_purchased) - interval 7 day from customer
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first group by `max()` `date_purchased` per `customer` id then join it to get `orderdate` less than 7 days from your date of purchase.

```
select distinct(customerid) 
from customer t1
inner join
    (select max(date_purchased) date_purchased, customerid as date_purchased 
        from customer group by customerid) t2
        on t2.customerid = t1.customerid
where datediff(t2.date_purchased, t1.Orderdate) <= 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation, if you prefer:

```
select customerid
from customer
group by customerid
having max(date_purchased) > max(max(datepurchased)) over () - interval 7 day;
```